# How to pass large data set between controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently passing retrieved data using `redirect_to` which uses `GET`. Since in some cases data set is large, URI is too long and throws `Bad Request` error.

All online research says its a bad idea to pass data in GET body. Is there a better way to pass data to another controller?

**Code Block**

```
def create
    response_body = http_get('/data/I/want')
    parsed_result = JSON.parse(response_body)
    check_response(parsed_result)
    redirect_to controller: :search_results, action: :index, results: parsed_result
end
```

end point called in `create` is search results so need to check if results are empty before redirecting and passing the data. I omitted this part from the code block

Comment: Put it in the db and read in the other controller? Or write it to a file perhaps?

Comment: @Iceman I might as well call the endpoint in the other controller, however, there are checks that I want to apply (I omitted them to keep the code block small) before redirecting to a new controller, hence a new view

Comment: You could use memcache to do this, if you don't want to write/read from the DB.  Another way is to 'render' the view that the second controller-action renders, from the first controller-action - though that might require moving some of the 'work' done in the 2nd controller to a model or elsewhere, so both controller-actions can access it.  This is how I solved a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to put these code in `create` method? From my point of view, your code doesn't really create anything. It is just get some JSON data from a remote URL and redirect to `search_results#index`. Why not just load the JSON in `search_results#index` directly?

**Update**

It is too generous to use more than 3 routes for a search action. I have two suggestions:

1. Search in remote JSON if you can control it. Just pass the searching keyword in URL and let remote resolve it.
2. If you cannot control the remote JSON, do the search with AJAX call. In your `search_results#index`, makes an AJAX call to your something like `search#new` JSON route and fetch the filtered result.

Comment: I removed some checks I have in my code to keep the block small but it checks if there are any results before redirecting to new controller(hence new view). I dont want to redirect until im sure there are results to be displayed. If I fetch in my display page `search_results#index` and there are no results, I will need to redirect back to `search#new` for another search. Hope that makes sense